# Problem on displaying UIPickerView value on TextEditor swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm having a problem displaying a value selected from a UIPickerView on a UITextField. I added all required functions to make it work but the textfield doesn't get updated.

Here is the ViewController.swift code

```
@IBOutlet weak var requestDestination: UITextField!

var itemSelected : String?
var pickerData = ["Bollate" , "Baranzate" , "Garbagnate" , "Novate Milanese" , "Paderno Dugnano" , "Certosa"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let thePicker = UIPickerView()
    thePicker.delegate = self
    thePicker.dataSource = self

    requestDestination.inputView = thePicker

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

private func pickerView( pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    itemSelected = pickerData[row]
    requestDestination.text = itemSelected
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    requestDestination.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I attached a screenshot where i show the first TextEdit that doesn't get the value from PickerView.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong `didSelectRow` signature so it is never called. You missed the `_`. Let Xcode complete the methods for you instead of trying to type them yourself.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
```

Comment: Fixed , really thanks. I couldn't imagine that fix suggested by the IDE was the solution , sorry for spam question.